# How can I set cron to run certain commands every one and a half hours?

Tags: cron

How can I set cron to run certain commands every one and a half hours?

Answer (score 45):

That's not possible with a single expression in normal `cron`.

The best you could do without modifying the code is:

```
0 0,3,6,9,12,15,18,21 * * *  [cmd]
30 1,4,7,10,13,16,19,22 * * * [cmd]
```

These *might* be compressible, depending on the version of cron you have to:

```
0 */3 * * * [cmd]
30 1-23/3 * * * [cmd]
```

Answer (score 16):

Is there a good reason why you can't use 1 hour or 2 hours? It would be simpler for sure.

I haven't tried this personally, but you can find some info here on getting cron to run every 90 minutes: http://keithdevens.com/weblog/archive/2004/May/05/cron

An excert from the above link:

```
0 0,3,6,9,12,15,18,21 * * * <commands>
30 1,4,7,10,13,16,19,22 * * * <commands>
```

Comment: Which requirement?  First sentence questions the necessity of 1.5 hours, the second provides a blog post with information on how to do it every 1.5 hours.

Comment: Upvoted because the blog post answers the question correctly.

Comment: It didn't clearly reference that when I down-voted it.  It has been edited since to make it clear that the link is to a potential solution for the 90 minute question.

Answer (score 7):

Two lines in the crontab.  Along the lines of:

```
0 0,3,6,9,12,15,18,21 * * * /usr/bin/foo
30 1,4,7,10,13,16,19,22 * * * /usr/bin/foo
```

Answer (score 5):

You could do it with two crontab entries.  Each runs every three hours and they are offset by 90 minutes something like this:

0 0,3,6,9,12,15,18,21 * * *

30 1,4,7,10,13,16,19,22 * * *

Answer (score 2):

`*/10 * * * * root perl -e 'exit(time()%(90*60)>60)' && command`

90 — it is one and a half hour in minutes

"> 60" — I give to cron ability to delay the start of script during a minute

Also with help of this hack you can set any period with a minute resolution

For example start the script every 71 minutes

`* * * * * root perl -e 'exit(time()%(71*60)>60)' && command`

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve any frequency if you count the minutes(, hours, days, or weeks) since [Epoch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time), add a condition to the top of your script, and set the script to run every minute on your crontab:

```
#!/bin/bash

minutesSinceEpoch=$(($(date +'%s / 60')))

# every 90 minutes (one and a half hours)
if [[ $(($minutesSinceEpoch % 90)) -ne 0 ]]; then
    exit 0
fi
```

[`date(1)`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/date) returns current date, we format it as seconds since Epoch (`%s`) and then we do basic maths:

```
# .---------------------- bash command substitution
# |.--------------------- bash arithmetic expansion
# || .------------------- bash command substitution
# || |  .---------------- date command
# || |  |   .------------ FORMAT argument
# || |  |   |      .----- formula to calculate minutes/hours/days/etc is included into the format string passed to date command
# || |  |   |      |
# ** *  *   *      * 
  $(($(date +'%s / 60')))
# * *  ---------------
# | |        | 
# | |        ·----------- date should result in something like "1438390397 / 60"
# | ·-------------------- it gets evaluated as an expression. (the maths)
# ·---------------------- and we can store it
```

And you may use this approach with hourly, daily, or monthly cron jobs:

```
#!/bin/bash
# We can get the

minutes=$(($(date +'%s / 60')))
hours=$(($(date +'%s / 60 / 60')))
days=$(($(date +'%s / 60 / 60 / 24')))
weeks=$(($(date +'%s / 60 / 60 / 24 / 7')))

# or even

moons=$(($(date +'%s / 60 / 60 / 24 / 656')))

# passed since Epoch and define a frequency
# let's say, every 7 hours

if [[ $(($hours % 7)) -ne 0 ]]; then
    exit 0
fi

# and your actual script starts here
```

Comment: Hi stefanmaric, since you seem to be firm in the matter, please add the answer to only one of the questions and flag those who are real duplicates as duplicates of the best question/answer combination.

Comment: Hi @bummi, I actually searched for the "mark as duplicate" feature. I didn't find it, so I posted. Doing more research since your comment, I found out I have not enough reputation to flag questions: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/118124/where-on-earth-is-the-mark-duplicate-ui-on-stack-overflow

Thanks for the advice and I'm sorry about the spam.

Answer (score 2):

use "[at](https://linuxize.com/post/at-command-in-linux/)" on crontab

the command is executed at midnight and then set to execute at 1.30

etc ..

`0 */3 * * * echo "Command" | at now +90 minutes && Command`

Answer (score 1):

You could also use [fcron](http://fcron.free.fr/) which also accepts more complex time specifications such as :

```
@ 01h30 my_cmd
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#! /bin/sh

# Minute Cron
# Usage: cron-min start
# Copyright 2014 by Marc Perkel
# docs at http://wiki.junkemailfilter.com/index.php/How_to_run_a_Linux_script_every_few_seconds_under_cron"
# Free to use with attribution

# Run this script under Cron once a minute

basedir=/etc/cron-min

if [ $# -gt 0 ]
then
   echo
   echo "cron-min by Marc Perkel"
   echo
   echo "This program is used to run all programs in a directory in parallel every X minutes."
   echo
   echo "Usage: cron-min"
   echo
   echo "The scheduling is done by creating directories with the number of minutes as part of the"
   echo "directory name. The minutes do not have to evenly divide into 60 or be less than 60."
   echo
   echo "Examples:"
   echo "  /etc/cron-min/1      # Executes everything in that directory every 1  minute"
   echo "  /etc/cron-min/5      # Executes everything in that directory every 5  minutes"
   echo "  /etc/cron-min/13     # Executes everything in that directory every 13 minutes"
   echo "  /etc/cron-min/90     # Executes everything in that directory every 90 minutes"
   echo
   exit
fi

for dir in $basedir/* ; do
   minutes=${dir##*/}
   if [ $(( ($(date +%s) / 60) % $minutes )) -eq 0 ]
   then
      for program in $basedir/$minutes/* ; do
     if [ -x $program ]
     then
        $program &> /dev/null &
     fi
      done
   fi
done
```

Answer (score -4):

added the following to my crontab and is working

```
15 */1   * * *   root    /usr/bin/some_script.sh >> /tmp/something.log
```