# How do I schedule a cron job to run every hour and a half?

Tags: cron

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I set cron to run certain commands every one and a half hours?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/247626/how-can-i-set-cron-to-run-certain-commands-every-one-and-a-half-hours)

I know that every two hours is:

```
* */2 * * * command-to-run
```

but how do I schedule a `cron` job to run every hour and a half?

Answer (score 3):

You can do this as *two* cron jobs:

```
0   0,3,6,9,12,15,18,21  * * * myprog myargs
30  1,4,7,10,13,16,19,22 * * * myprog myargs
```

This has the advantage of working on even ancient systems that don't support the `/2`-type syntax.

Answer (score 0):

I think you would need two cronjobs that run every three hours and are offset by 1.5 hours.