# fire job every 90 min continuously

Tags: cron, quartz-scheduler

How should I go about creating a cron expression that will fire every 90 minutes continuously after midnight?
Documentation here:
http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-1.x/tutorials/crontrigger

Pratik

Comment: see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/247626/how-can-i-set-cron-to-run-certain-commands-every-one-and-a-half-hours

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would just configure *two* cron jobs:

```
#min hr                     everything else
 0   0,3,6,9,12,15,18,21    ...
30   1,4,7,10,13,16,19,22   ...
```

(you could also use the short form for the hours as well, like `0-21/3` and `1-22/3`).

Comment: paxdiablo, could you explain the 0-21/3 and 1-22/3?  Should I use them like <cron-expression>30 0-21/3 * * *</cron-expression>
<cron-expression>30 1-22/3 * * *</cron-expression>  or do I need to consider the position for seconds?

Comment: Oh, I think I understand. /3 is indicating the increments from 0 onwards and same for the other one.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Don't use CronTrigger for such a schedule.  Use one of the other trigger types such as SimpleTrigger or CalendarIntervalTrigger etc.